# Trying to Update AttributedText for UIButton

Tags: swift, uibutton, nsattributedstring

I'm new here and in Swift. I am trying to update one of attributed text of the `UIButton`, specifically color of it. I found an option that seems can do it, but I have an error. Please help (see code below). If there are other options, please, let me know.

```swift
@IBAction func btnsPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.updateTextAttributes(conversionHandler: convertToOptionalNSAttributedStringKeyDictionary([ NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor.rawValue : UIColor.orange]))
}
```

I have the following error: Cannot convert value of type `[NSAttributedString.Key : Any]?` to expected argument type `([NSAttributedString.Key : Any]) -> [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]`

Comment: Could be help you https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponderstandardeditactions/3261459-updatetextattributes

Comment: This helped me: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/127226. It's partly the same that @Mahmut posted, but also solves my problem with different titles...

Answer (score 3):

```swift
// .Selected
let selectedAttributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Submit", 
                                                 attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.green])
btnTap.setAttributedTitle(selectedAttributedTitle, for: .selected)

// .Normal
let normalAttributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Submit",
                                               attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.red])
btnTap.setAttributedTitle(normalAttributedTitle, for: .normal)
```

Try above code, its will be work.

Comment: Good answer, thanks. But this IBAction that I have is a collection of `UIButtons` (more than 10 buttons in there) and each of them have different titles, so your example would change title all of them to "Submit" and I don't need that.